# Understanding stdClass objects

Tags: php, json, object, stdclass

Alright, I am "kind of" new to stdClass objects in PHP and I am experimenting a bit to get an understanding in exporting data / creating APIs to get information from the database with relevant information.

So, what I want is giving a user access to some information from, lets say a database or XML-file (not everything just some parts). (In this case it's a local sqlite3 file) and I want to give the user the data in JSON-format.

What is it I need help with? For short - I would like to get some advice from you to solve the "problem" in a smarter way than I already got. (I guess my way is kind of... ugly solution.

This is the current export of the structure that I export (without JSON-encode): http://codepaste.net/965tgj

I have done this by the following way in a php file: (The $users is acually data from sqlite3.db and I do understand that to the fullest how to use, so I slimmed the code down :)

```
$users = array(
    array(
        "id" => 1,
        "user" => "Xavizus"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 2,
        "user" => "Zariel"
    )
);

$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->auth = true;
$obj->usercount = 2;
$obj->users = array();

for($i =0; $i < $obj->usercount; $i++){
        $obj->users[] = new stdClass();
}

for($i = 0; $i < $obj->usercount; $i++) {
        $obj->users[$i]->id = $users[$i]['id'];
        $obj->users[$i]->user = $users[$i]['user'];
}

print_r($obj);
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this? or is this as cleanest I can go for?

Comment: You should define your own class and have the constructor accept initialization values. That would be a lot cleaner.

Comment: Be sure to get your stdClasses tested...

Comment: @jeroen Thank you for the tip :) (As I said before - I am kind of new in PHP and I am still learning - I got to say - This is an awesome community!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be easier using `(object)` to cast the array:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->auth = true;
$obj->usercount = count($users);
$obj->users = $users;

foreach($obj->users as &$user) {
    $user = (object)$user;
}
```

However I would look into @jeroen's comment: "*You should define your own class and have the constructor accept initialization values. That would be a lot cleaner*."

```
class users {

    function __construct($users, $auth=true) {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->usercount = count($users);        

        foreach($users as $user) {
            $this->users[] = (object)$user;
        }
    }
}

$obj = new users($users);
```

You could also cast the row array to an object when assigning it from the `fetchArray()`.

Comment: Thank you for the the excellent explanation :) Didn't really expect that this community was this helpful :)

Comment: Okey - I don't find the reputation button....
Edit: Nvm.... Just needed to press the answer button and answer vote :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in one for loop right?

instead of

```
for($i =0; $i < $obj->usercount; $i++){
        $obj->users[] = new stdClass();
}

for($i = 0; $i < $obj->usercount; $i++) {
        $obj->users[$i]->id = $users[$i]['id'];
        $obj->users[$i]->user = $users[$i]['user'];
}
```

you can do it something like

```
for($i =0; $i < $obj->usercount; $i++){
        $newObject = new stdClass();
        $newObject->id = $users[$i]['id'];
        $newObject->user = $users[$i]['user'];
        $obj->users[] = $newObject;
}
```